# Create a custom route in Angular using $resource

Tags: angularjs

EDIT: I should have been clearer on at least one point: I'd like to do the following using my existing Service. It might not be possible, but something like

```
return $resource(CONSTANTS.API + 'computer/:id/:action'...
```

[seemed plausible](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource), where `:action` could be the optional `ping`.

Back to initial question...

So, I have an external api that responds to this route:

```
localhost/api/computers/:id/ping
```

Now I want to create an angular service that can send requests to that route. My existing service looks like this:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('computer')
        .factory('ComputerService', ComputerResource);

    ComputerResource.$inject = ['$resource', 'CONSTANTS'];

    function ComputerResource ($resource, CONSTANTS) {
        return $resource(CONSTANTS.API + 'computer/:id',
            {id: '@id'},
            {
                'update': {
                    method:'PUT'
                }
            }
        );
    };
})();
```

I would like to be able to use my theoretical `$resource` something like this:

```
ComputerService.ping({id: $stateParams.id})
    .$promise.then(function (data) {
        ...
    });
```

I think I need to add `ping` to the `$resource` somehow and then...I dunno.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Should work fine appending `/ping` to your url string

```
function ComputerResource ($resource, CONSTANTS) {
        return $resource(CONSTANTS.API + 'computer/:id/ping',
            {id: '@id'},
            {
                'update': {
                    method:'PUT'
                }
            }
        );
    };
```

Comment: That seems to break some of my other routes.

Comment: need to be more specific than that. Is it using expected url in dev tools network?

Comment: The above `$resource` covers a number of standard routes. Adding `ping` to the end breaks those other routes (`query`, `get`, `create` and `update`).

Comment: then create a different resource or create a custom method that has ping in url